# Full list of functions, commands for MS Word from c++

Tags: c++, com, ms-word

I'm working with word through my c++ application. And I want to read some documentation about available opportunities. I see some piece of code of some paticular situations (to add a picture, to add text, to save file, to fill table) in forums, but I want to observe all functions.

Tell me where can I get such documentation or how to find it.

Comment: You can get it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/). And less sarcasticly and more usefully http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726434

Answer (score 1):

The full documentation can be found on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff841702